# Where to put non liferay (plain java) project

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, organization

this may seem like a trival question, but it bugs me. In Liferay, there are some recommendations / requirements on where to put projects:

- `Portlets` should be placed in `plugins-sdk/portlets`
- `Hooks`should be placed in `plugins-sdk/hooks`
- `Exts`should be placed in `plugins-sdk/ext`

But where do I put other project (plain java)?

In my case, I have a lib with common code used in multiple portlets. I want to place it somewhere, that makes it easy (kiss) to use for build tools like gradle and/or ant.

The vcs is another thing. Should I import the whole sdk folder?

Thanks in advance, Fabi

Comment: you can create some folder say utilities and put your project there

Answer (score 1):

Our solution was to create an external project that was shipped as a Jar file and we set it up as a dependency for all the portlet and other projects.

Under external I mean that it is not even managed under `plugins-sdk`, it was even at a different VCS (well, technically it was under `plugins-sdk` to speed up updating the Jar, help debugging and stuff, but was on ignore). This is important so you can easily reuse your library for additional Liferay projects, you can even manage different branches for multiple Liferay versions, etc.